# Linux xargs command

Tags: linux, xargs

A quick question.
A command

```
cat * | wc -c
```

doesn't require xargs, but the command

```
ls | xargs echo
```

requires xargs command.
Can please someone explain me the concept of xargs more clearly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, `xargs` converts `stdin` (standard input) to arguments for the command you specify. For example

```
$ seq 1 3
1
2
3
$ seq 1 3 | xargs echo
1 2 3
```

`seq`, as you can see, prints a sequence to `stdout`. We pipe (`|`) that output to `xargs` on `stdin`. `xargs` calls `echo` with `stdin` as arguments, so we get `echo 1 2 3`.

As [el.pescado said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32972505/802618), `wc` accepts input on `stdin` (you can also give it a file argument). Because `cat` prints a file to `stdout`, you can pipe it directly to `wc`.

```
$ cat text
This is only
a test
$ cat text | wc
      2       5      20
$ wc text
 2  5 20 text
```

`echo` does not accept anything from `stdin`. That would be weird, since `echo`'s job is to print to `stdout` - you could already print anything you'd pipe it. So, you use `xargs` to convert the stream to arguments.

`echo` might be too trivial a command to see what's going on, so here's a more real-world example. Say we've got a directory with some files in it:

```
$ ls
bar1 foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 foo5 foo6
```

We've had it up to here with `foo`, and we want to delete all of them, but we can't be bothered to type `rm foo1 foo2 ...`. After all, we're programmers, and we're lazy. What we can do is...

```
$ ls foo* | xargs rm
$ ls
bar1
```

`rm` expects arguments, `ls foo*` prints every file we want to remove, and `xargs` does the translation.

---

As a side note, sometimes you want to split up `stdin` into smaller pieces. `xargs -n` is highly useful for that, and passes N arguments at a time to your final command.

```
$ ls foo* | xargs -n2 echo
foo1 foo2
foo3 foo4
foo5 foo6
```

Answer (score 1):

`wc` reads data from its *standard input*, whereas `echo` prints its *command line arguments*.